# Operation failed with 0x8007000B

Tags: asp.net, command-prompt

I am administrator on my machine but when I am trying to run :

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir
```

i am getting this error:

[image]

Also tried : C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -i but this returns the same error.

Comment: have you looked at the event logs?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error , what fixed is below ,

go to

-Add/RemovePrograms 
-Turn Windows features on or off 
-Internet Information Services 
-World Wide Web Services

enable checkbox for ASP.NET .